# User spamming link to their YouTube channel

Tags: support, status-completed, spam

The user [ExcelVbaIsFun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2301211/excelvbaisfun) has spammed his URL in all 8 answers, and shows no signs of stopping.

I've edited 5 answers, and 3 other people have edited the others.

Can something be done to stop him posting that same URL repeatedly? His last answer was 1 min ago.

Numerous people have @inbox'd him.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We've sent the user a warning. Let us know either in an edit or a flag if the behavior continues.

Answer (score 7):

**Don't leave any further comments.** As you mention it's been done already and hasn't helped.

Flag one of the answers for moderator attention, use the *Other* reason and explain that the user is persistently promoting his youtube channel in a spammy way. The mod will then action the flag and determine the appropriate course of action, which may be a mod message to the user and/or a short ban.

Using a valid blog entry or external link to support your answer [like he has here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16127749/109702) is fine provided you are open when it is your own blog (text like *"check out my blog post which explains the answer more fully"* would be satisfactory), although it is preferred that he excerpts sufficient material from the supporting external post for the answer to make sense - IOW the answer shouldn't be just a link.

Straight out promotional links [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16127661/1) are deemed spam and must be stamped on. It would seem that this user's primary purpose here is to promote his youtube channel using the guise of answering questions - like no-one has tried that before!! Sucks to be him though because all new users have a `rel=nofollow` inserted into their links, as you can see from this snippet from his [surviving answer with a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16127749/109702):

```
<p>Links here:<br>
<a href="http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/611558-visual-basic-applications-create-unique-list-range-data.html" rel="nofollow">Create Unique list</a><br>
<a href="http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=40545" rel="nofollow">Create Unique list 2</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, leave a comment asking that he not use a tag-ling or signature, and linking to [that section of the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) (It appears you have already done this). Chat pings **do not count** as the OP won't receive them unless he has visited chat in the last 3 days.

If he persists then you should custom flag the answer and explain that this user has been using a signature spamming his youtube channel and won't stop after receiving several comments.

The moderators will handle it from there.  If he absolutely refuses to stop (which isn't likely) he will probably get a short ban.

Answer (score 0):

You should leave a comment on any one of his posts. If he doesn't react to that raise a flag on any of his answers and fill out your explanation in the other option so that a moderator can deal with him.

Additionally, users do not always get chat pings unless they have visited chat recently (or it is a super ping by a moderator).

Also, for future reference, please do not explicitly name and link to users on Meta. This can cause certain problems, and you should flag the post for private moderator attention whenever possible.